# Angular 8 & Laravel echo websockets with socket io: Socket.io client not found

Tags: angular, laravel, sockets, socket.io

I got Laravel running locally with `php artisan serve`, installed laravel-echo-server with  `npm install -g laravel-echo-server` then I run the command `laravel-echo-server init` to generate a laravel-echo-server.json:

```
{
    "authHost": "http://localhost",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "secureOptions": 67108864,
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": true,
        "allowOrigin": "http://localhost:8001",
        "allowMethods": "GET, POST",
        "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
    }
}
```

Then I run the command `laravel-echo-server start` to start the server which results in [this console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnKJ0.png), then I run the command `php artisan queue:listen` to listen to the queue and then finally I start tinker console to run my event. This is just a basic event with a 'test' message:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class TestEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    private $message = 'test';

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['test-channel'];
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'test';
    }
}
```

In angular I set-up the following:

```
this.echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001',
});

this.echo.connector.socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('CONNECTED');
});

this.echo.connector.socket.on('reconnecting', function () {
    console.log('CONNECTING');
});

this.echo.connector.socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('DISCONNECTED');
});

this.echo.channel('test-channel')
    .listen('.test', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
});
```

However, when I start the angular client I get the following message:
[Socket.io client not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt9qO.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a socketio-client to angular.json

```
npm i socket.io-client
```

// in angular.json

```
"options": {        
    "scripts": [
        "node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"
     ]
}
```